Problemas con JavaScritp y las Promesas
Estoy iniciándome con JavaScipt y estoy intentando crear un buscador en tiempo real con AJAX, PHP, JavaScript y MySQL.
Cuando ejecuto el archivo search_data si que me muestra, haciendo un echo, el JSON($authors) que genera, pero cuando lo corro desde el index me vuelca, en la consola, el siguiente error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "

<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON

Promise.then(asíncrono)
showResults @ script.js:35
(anónimo)   @ script.js:11

¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme a qué se debe este error?.
search_data: Fichero que lleva a cabo la consulta en la base de datos.
<?php
    require_once("config/conectar.php");    

    $search_criteria = $_POST['search_criteria'];   

    $query = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email, birthday, added FROM empleados 
    WHERE first_name LIKE '%" .$search_criteria. "%'
    OR last_name LIKE '%" .$search_criteria. "%'";
        
    $authors=[];
    $errors=['data'=>false];

    $getAuthors = $db->query($query);

    if ($getAuthors->num_rows > 0){
        while($data = $getAuthors->fetch_assoc()){
            $authors[] = $data;
        }
        echo json_encode($authors);     
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode($errors);
    }
    
?>

script.js: Fichero para generar la comunicacíon asíncrona AJAX
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>{
     const search = document.querySelector("#search");
     const tableContainer = document.querySelector("#results tbody");  
     const resultsContainer = document.querySelector("#resultsContainer");
     const errorsContainer = document.querySelector(".error-container");  
     let search_criteria =""; 

     if (search) {
        search.addEventListener("input", event => {
            search_criteria = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
            showResults();
        })
     }

     //Enviar petición usando fetch

     const searchData = async ()=> {
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("search_criteria", search_criteria);

        try {
            const response = await fetch("search_data.php", {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData
            });
            return response.json();
            
        } catch (error) {
            alert ("Hubo un error y no se puede procesar la solicitud");
        }                
        };

        const showResults = () => {
            searchData()
            .then(dataResults => {
                console.log(dataResults);
            })
        }

    });


El mensaje SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ocurre porque estás esperando un JSON, pero en el código de servidor estaba saliendo por pantalla otra cosa distinta de un json, debido probablemente a algún error en el código de servidor.

El error no prevenía de ninguno de estos ficheros y venía del HTML donde la línea  estaba apuntando de manera incorrecta al fichero.
